prove there exists a non-adaptive PRF that is not an (adaptive) PRF
A function family is a non-adaptive PRF, if it is a PRF s,but
its security should only holds against non-adaptive distinguishers
(non-adaptive distinguishers make all there queries at
once)prf

Hint: take a secure PRF and modify it (insert a backdoor) so that it is vulnerable to adaptive distinguishers (but not nonadaptive ones)

@qqq Could you please elaborate on the definitions for non-adaptive and adaptive PRFs so that I can answer according to your definitions? This will also be useful to those who are reading your question.

@MaheshSR  regular prf is both adaptive prf and non-adaptive prf.
non-adaptive prf is secured against against non adaptive ppt distinguisher (non-adaptive distinguishers make all there queries at once)
adaptive distinguishers  can choose his next query according to the previous queries answer which is more powerful
my goal as poncho suggested is to weaken regular prf to only non-adaptive prf

@poncho my try is this:
assume $F={F_n:{0,1}^{m(n)} →{0,1}^{l(n)}}$ is a prf define G function family as follow:$ G_s(x) = \begin{Bmatrix} F_s(x)||01 & if \ s\lt x \F_s(x)||11 & if \ s\gt x  \ s||10 & if \  x=s \end{Bmatrix}$
but my problem is that non adaptive distinguisher D can attack as follow
from i =0 till i =n define  question i in binary and ask the orcale
if all the answers suffix till some point are 01
answer that this orcale is G else answer that it is truly random
